# Padding for Text() within Column not working?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I have a Jetpack Compose composable in a column beginning with a icon, title, textbody and a pager row:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .background(color = TVTheme.colors.blue)
) {

val bigPadding = 334.dp
val smallPadding = 24.dp

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredSize(164.dp, 28.dp),
            icon = R.drawable.calendar_a_icon
        )
        

        // title
        val title = "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit"
        if (title.isNotEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = title,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.vertical), start = bigPadding, end = bigPadding)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                overflow = TextOverflow.Visible
            )
        }

        // body
        val body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit."
        if (body.isNotEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = body,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.vertical), start = bigPadding, end = bigPadding)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                overflow = TextOverflow.Visible
            )
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 44.dp, bottom = smallPadding, start = smallPadding, end = smallPadding)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {

            val text = AnnotatedString.Builder(item.skipButtonText).toAnnotatedString()

            ClickableText(
                maxLines = 1,
                text = "Skip",
                onClick = {
                    skip()
                }
            )

            Pager(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                index = currentPageIndex,
                pageNumbers = totalPages)
        }
    }
}
```

which produces this screen:[image]

The left and right paddings for the title and body is set to 334.dp. The example screenshot has a width of 1800 dp and according to proportions the paddings are much more than given 334.dp. **That would mean, the width of title and body is 1132.dp ?!**:
[image]

I tried to make the proportions visible.
**How can I apply correct paddings for title and body text composables?**

Comment: try to use fillMaxWidth on column. It is possible that column is trying to shrink its size. however, it should work to conquer as much space as possible.